# Testcomplete click on Checkbox using Xpath

Tags: html, xpath, testcomplete

I do have the following html text:

```
<tr class="off" onmouseout="this.className='off'"onmouseover="this.className='over'">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:personSelecti‌​on" id="caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:personSelection‌​" value="true" />
</td>
<td><span id="caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:extClientId">11‌​1</span>
</td>
<td><span id="caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:clientName">SAM‌​UEL</span>
</td>
```

I am trying to click on the checkbox which has the data 111 in the same row.

I am trying to something like this:

> page.FindChildByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'111')]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/input[@name='caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:personSelection']",false)

but I get object not found error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have merged your HTML into the question and added some more appropriate tags. You can add things to improved the detail in the question by clicking on the [edit] button like I did. Hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkox has an ID, and IDs are unique within a page. So you can use:

```js
// JScript
var checkBox = page.FindChildByXPath("//input[@id='caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:0:personSelection‌​']");
checkBox.ClickChecked(true); // Check the checkbox
```

The ID contains a number (0); you can use a variable to specify this number:

```js
var checkBox = page.FindChildByXPath("//input[@id='caller_enrollment_form:enrollmentParticipantSelectionTable:" + index + ":personSelection‌​']");
```

If you specifically need to identify by the text "111", you can use something like this:

```js
var checkBox = page.FindChildByXPath("//tr[td/span[.='111']]/td/input");
checkBox.ClickChecked(true); // Check the checkbox
```

You can also use a variable instead of "111":

```js
var checkBox = page.FindChildByXPath("//tr[td/span[.='" + text + "']]/td/input");
```

XPath explanation:

```
//tr                   - find a table row
    [                  - that matches this condition:
      td/span[.='111'] - any of the row's cells contains a SPAN with the text '111'
    ]
                       - then in this row
 /td/input             - find an INPUT in any cell
```

Comment: Thanks Helen... I wish I could use the first answer but the number 0 in the Id keeps changing ... It's the row number.. Is there a way I could append row index in th I'd field- something like 'caller...'+RowIndex+':personSelection'?? I will try the second option and see. Appreciate ur help

Comment: I tried the second option as well. Here also for every run my  span text changes it will be 112 next time. So how will I insert dynamic values inside the FindChildByXPath function?

Comment: Thanks Helen ..I got it to work with: FindChildByXPath("//tr[td/span[.='"+CIN+"']]/td/input");  Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @test: Glad to help! I added the XPath explanation to the answer.